# How to cast AQMessage STRUCT object to UDT object

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-aq

Trying to read a message with UDT payload from oracle AQ queue in java. I used jpub to create java classes for my Oraacle UDT/Object in the database (object called MESSAGE_TYP).

jpub output:

```
public class message_typ implements ORAData, ORADataFactory ...
```

Then deuque message and get STRUCT:

```
oracle.jdbc.aq.AQMessage msg = conn.dequeue(queueName, deqopt, "MESSAGE_TYP");
STRUCT st = msg.getSTRUCTPayload();
```

So How do I then get to my concrete message_typ object reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  After call to msg.getSTRUCTPayload():

```
    message_typ typ;  // My UDT created with jpub
    ORADataFactory of = message_typ.getORADataFactory();
    ORAData od = of.create(st, 1);
    typ = (message_typ)od;
```